# Use Gingerbread styled menu in Android

Tags: android, menu, android-2.3-gingerbread

UPDATE: Drawing my own menu now. Thanks everyone.

I've googled around on the topic, but pretty much all I found was around changing the target build number.

I was wondering if there is some other way to use the old fashioned menu as in Gingerbread on newer versions of Android.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Just saying, developers are now discouraged from doing this and encouraged to use the Holo style instead.

Comment: yeah, I understand that. But the client wanted that in the UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you could try putting the default theme in. This changes the button styles too, so that can be a negative effect. I am also not sure whether it will change the menu styles, but it is definetly worth a shot.

Add the following into your XML

`<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme">`

This should remove the holo theme, if it doesn't you can play around with some other themes until you find one which works. This might help - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

If that doesn't work your could try overriding the menu button to pull up a custom menu. Here is some code to override the menu button -

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
        //put code to call up your custom menu here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: I added another possible solution,

Comment: yep, I'm going to draw my own custom menu now.